# module.export and node.js. I'm loosing my mind over 4 lines of codes and I don't understand the issue at all

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently learning node.js using udemy and I'm having an issue that I absolutely don't understand because it shouldn't be happening.

So the lecture is about accessing external files using node.js with module.exports. I followed exactly the video and it was not working.

here is the code of app.js

```
require('./utils.js')

console.log(name);
```

and here is utils.js

```
const name = 'test' ;

module.exports = name;
```

Dead simple right ? But it wasn't working. I would get this error :

```
iMac-de-user:notes-app user$ node app.js
utils.js
/Users/user/Desktop/notes-app/app.js:3
console.log(name)
            ^
 
ReferenceError: name is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/notes-app/app.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
iMac-de-user:notes-app user$
```

So app.js couldn't access the constant name from utils.js (even though my code was exactly the same than the one on the video at this point.) So I downloaded the finished project from the ressources and it was pretty much the same except it was a function that was being exported.

```
const getNotes = function () {
    return 'Your notes...'
}

module.exports = getNotes
```

I tried it and it worked. So at first I thought that maybe it could access functions and not variables ? It was weird because the trainer did it but that was the only explanation. So I kept it and deleted the function to just add a console.log

```
    const getNotes = console.log('test');
    
    module.exports = getNotes
```

It worked. At that point I was weirded out because it was pretty much my first code. So i tried changing the names to name again (of course I changed it in the console.log() in app.js as well) and it didnt work. I checked if maybe it was a reserved keyword ? nope. I tried test testTest Name Name1 nameName. Nothing works, nothing except getNotes(everytime I would change the name in app.js and utils.js so a total a 3 constant names changed.)

I don't understand, to the best of my knowledge this is not possible and doesn't make any sense

What's going on ? Is my computer haunted ? It's probably something very stupid but I can't figure it out. I understand it might be a bit confusing so I included 2 pictures.

Thank you for your time.

[image: picture 1]
[image: picture2]

Comment: require() fortunately doesn't put variables into the global scope, you have to assign the result of require to a variable. some languages, like ruby, pollute the global scope with imports, which is bad practice

Comment: Thanks Andy Ray. Do you have any idea why it worked when the variable was called getNotes though ?

Comment: @altho There's no good reason. It absolutely shouldn't have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like below you have to store the object or variable exported in a new variable after `requiring` it .Make sure you give the correct path in `require` statement.

```
const name=require('./utils.js')
console.log(name);
```

Exporting it

```
const name = 'test' ;

module.exports = name;
```

Also see [here](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/)

Comment: Thank you. It does work but I still don't understand why it worked with getNotes and nothing else or why it worked fine on the video ?

Comment: So I checked the lecture again and he does store require in a constant so it was a mistake on my part.